# IOS 5 static tableview cell no background color

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make a table cell completely transparent. I am using static table cell in iOS 5 and tried change to clear color, but it does

I even tried (in viewDidLoad)

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

But the whole table is black and the cell is white. (See photo)[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` - will change the background color of the tableview not the cells.

Try selecting the individual cells in Interface Builder and using the inspector to change the cell background to a color or nothing for transparent.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell           
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `[cell setOpaque:FALSE]` and [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]] in cellForRowAtIndexPath: